# Serializing PsObject for Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm looking for the best or proper way to pass a PsObject to a remote function with Invoke-Command. ConvertTo-Xml is good for serializing but there is no built-in reverse cmdlet.  The solutions I've found online are all content specific.

I implemented the following functions which works with the few objects I tested but seems rather hacky. Is this going to bite me?  Is there a better, yet still simple solution?

```
function Get-TmpFileName () {...}

function Serialize-PsObject($obj) {
    $tmpFile = Get-TmpFileName
    Export-Clixml -InputObject $obj -Path $tmpFile
    $serializedObj = Get-Content $tmpFile
    Remove-Item $tmpFile
    $serializedObj
}

function Deserialize-PsObject($obj) {
    $tmpFile = Get-TmpFileName
    $obj > $tmpFile
    $deserializedObj = Import-Clixml $tmpFile
    Remove-Item $tmpFile
    $deserializedObj
}
```

Comment: if you have PSv3+ you can use the $Using. In PowerShell 3.0, variables prefixed with $using: are automatically recognized as local variables and are sent to the remote machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you aware that PowerShell already serializes objects sent through `Invoke-Command`?

If for some reason that isn't enough or isn't working for you, then you can use use the built-in serialization yourself directly:

```
$clixml = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($object)
$object = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($clixml)
```

`.Serialize` has an overload where you can specify the depth (for objects within objects).

These are the same methods used in implementing `Export-Clixml` and `Import-Clixml` (but those cmdlets work directly with files and not strings).

Comment: I tried passing the PsObject through the Invoke-Command but it did not seem to deserialize properly on the remote end.  I will try it again today then edit my question with the problem symptoms.  Thanks.

Comment: I was messing up my scriptblock before it was sent to the server.  Now it works as I had first expected it would.  I still like that you can manually serialize when necessary without going to the file system.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I needed for a scenario where the returned object from Invoke-Command was not being serialized enough. Wish Invoke-Command had a depth option built in. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `ConvertTo-JSON?`